# Nested List serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, silverlight-3.0

I am having problem transfering my object from WCF to SL3.

```
interface IComposite {
   ICollection<Child_A> Children{ get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
[knownType(typeof(ChildCollection))]
[knownType(typeof(ICollection<Child_A>))]
class Composite : IComposite {
    ChildCollection c = null;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Child_A> Children { get { 
         return c??(c=new ChildCollection()); 
    }  set;}
}
[CollectionDataContract]
class ChildCollection : List<Child_A> {
}
[DataContract]
class Child_A {
    [DataMember]
    string Name { get;set; }
}
[OperationContract]
Composite GetData(){
   var data = new Composite();
   data.Children.Add( new Child_A() { Name = "child_a_1" } );
   return data;
}
```

When I call the service from SL3, I get the `Composite` object but no item in the list. There are other collection in `Composite`. When I set `[DataMember(Order=0/1)]` I get error nullreference error on client. And if I remove it, I get error Not Found. I tried `KnowType` and `ServiceKnownType` but did not work. I checked svcTrace, it simply says Serialization Error. Where I am doing wrong.

**SVC TRACE**
The InnerException message was 'Type 'xxxCoverageEntity' with data contract name 'xxxCoverageEntity : http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxxBusinessEntities' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types

Here xxxCoverageEntity is Child_A in sample

Comment: Hey, maybe have you got solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the collection with `DataMember` or it will not get serialized at all. You will also need to annotate the `DataContract` with `KnownType(typeof(ChildCollection))` as otherwise it doesn't know what type of "thing" the `ICollection` is and therefore how to serialize it

Similarly you will need to add `[DataMember]` to `Child_A` `Name` property or it will not get serialized

Comment: I tried this before and now, but at client I get NullReference exception. Updated post is what I have now

Comment: The moment I remove [DataMember] from Children property, it serialize with empty list, otherwise nullreference exception

Comment: Can you check if this is purely a Silverlight thing by creating a console App and calling the service?

Comment: Should the code in GetData read `data.Children.Add`? You don't have an Add operation on composite according to what you have shown. Also can you turn on Message Logging in the service and just ensure that the data makes it out of the service?

Comment: Right its, children.add. Added trace from svcLog

Comment: Have you tried adding Child_A as a known type to the Composite data contract?

Comment: Yes, and WCF sends message succuessfully (no error in svclog). So probably deserializing issue.

Comment: Have you verified whether a console app works so we can isolate whether its a general issue or a silverlight thing?